# Laravel get $primary from scss into Blade

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-blade

I use Laravel with SCSS / Webmix. I have the file _variables.scss and set some variables like $primary and $secondary.

Now I want to use this variables in Blade especially in Mailtemplates. How can I realize this?

Can I load it directly from Blade template? Is it possible to get variables in Controller and pass it to Blade?

Answer (score 0):

Create a "configuration" json file e.g.

**config.json** and put it somewhere (e.g. in resources)

```
{
   "primary": "<Color>"
}
```

If you are using webpack with sass-loader then you can customise your loader rules:

```
const injectedColours = require('config.json');

 module: {
   rules: [
      {
        test: /\.sccs$/,
        use: [
          { 
             loader: 'scss-loader',
             options: {
                data: '$primary: ' + injectedColours.primary
             }
           }
        ]
       }
    ]
}
```

Then you can remove the `$primary` entry in your `_variables.scss` file.

If you're using Laravel mix you can refer to https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#custom-webpack-configuration on how you can merge the above in your default configuration

In your controller you can also read the same json file e.g.

```
$primary = json_decode(file_get_contents('config.json'))->primary;
```